# Running a command line app with sudo and password automatically on OS X startup 

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal, applescript

I need to run an app at startup/login on my mac. I want it to launch in the background and start doing it's work without interrupting me or me having to start it up because I invariably forget and then when I need it, it wasn't running!

I have tried using AppleScript to tell Terminal to run it and type my password in, but it ends up opening multiple Terminal windows and not working. Ideally I need a script that I can just add to the user login items and it will run for me.

The app has no way of taking a password argument either and it has a password as well as the sudo! I need a solution that can either be done as an applescript (which can be made into an executable) or i need a commandline script but I have no idea about them.

This is the manual code I type

```
$ sudo serverStatus
password:123456
password:serverpass
```

My AppleScript:

```
tell application Terminal
 activate
 do shell script "sudo serverStatus"
 delay 5
 do shell script "123456"
 delay 2
 do shell script "serverpass"
end tell
```

Comment: Is that app a custom-built one? What exactly is it? What AppleScript commands did you try?

Comment: It's a custom app built a while ago by a friend so I can do some server monitoring & logging but he is too busy to update it with the features I need (it was a freebie favor). I have updated my question with my applescript code I tried. It opened 3 windows and didn't seem to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do shell script` is used to execute shell scripts within an AppleScript and won't actually open a Terminal window. You could open a new Terminal window with `do script` and then emulate typing the passwords with `keystroke`.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "sudo serverStatus"
    activate
end tell
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "login password" & return
    delay 1
    keystroke "server password" & return
end tell
```

If you're up for it, you could also just use a [login hook](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2420) which would be run after logging into your user account. This hook could call the appropriate AppleScript with:

```
osascript /path/to/script.scpt
```

But this seems to be a little too much if you could just add it to the login items manually.

Comment: Thanks @Lauri – I wasn't on a machine where I could try this.

Comment: For those that found this wanting to open programs with spaces in the name, remember that it would be two backslashes.... example `do shell script "sudo /Applications/Aptana\\ Studio \\3/AptanaStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/AptanaStudio"

Comment: Just curious, why would Aptana need `sudo`? @sen